# Is there any other use for the items with a description along the lines of "sells for an x amount"?

Tags: octopath-traveler

I have a few different items in my inventory where the description reads something along the lines "sells for a modest amount".

Items examples are mysterious ore and fools gold.

Are these items safe to just sell or do they have any other kind of purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no other uses for these items. Without writing up an exhaustive list for each item, there is no way to be absolutely sure - but it is safe to say that each of these items are in the game for the sole purpose of selling for currency.

This is a common concept in many other RPGs, as well. For example, the Gold Nugget in Pokémon games.